# android intents alarmmanager

Tags: android, android-intent, alarmmanager

I am trying to create intents that will be set using alarmmanager. Currently, I can do this with one intent, add extra data to it (strings, but i send them as one string with a seperator), and everything works fine and goes off at the correct time. However, when I try to send multiple intents like this, they are overwritten and only one goes off at the correct time. How can i structure my intents so that they appear different to the alarmmanager (i think they are getting deleted when filterIntent() is run).

long story short- putExtra() makes all the intents look the same still... how can i make them look different so they wont get deleted (and keep track of them in case i want to delete a specific one)

Answer (score 0):

This is how I scheduled updates for my widgets. Each one allowed to be unique because they have a unique widget id number.

```
Intent widgetUpdate = new Intent();
widgetUpdate.setAction(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE);
widgetUpdate.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, new int[] { appWidgetId });
widgetUpdate.putExtra(EXTRA_POSITION,0);
widgetUpdate.putExtra(EXTRA_URL, URL);
// make this pending intent unique by adding a scheme to it
widgetUpdate.setData(Uri.withAppendedPath(Uri.parse(URI_SCHEME + "://widget/id/"), String.valueOf(appWidgetId)));
PendingIntent newPending = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, widgetUpdate, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
// schedule the updating
AlarmManager alarms = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarms.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(), updateRateSeconds * 1000, newPending);
```

Comment: And how do you retrieve data?

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs, `AlarmManager` checks if two `Intent`s are *equivalent* using [`filterEquals()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#filterEquals(android.content.Intent)). Check out the docs for `filterEquals()` to see how it decides whether two `Intent`s are equivalent. Also, **chris324**'s solution is a pretty good one.